# GPU and CPU mode, how do games do that?

Tags: 3d, game-design, performance

I'm playing a lot of older games lately to learn new stuff, mostly private servers.

A game called metin-2 has the option to use mostly CPU or mostly GPU... in GPU mode the game runs faster and lighter than this actual browser I'm writing from...and I was playing a private server with a ton of players, I'm not exagerating when I say there were at least 500 players all smashed and squeezed tightly in a small city throwing all kind of effects, sounds and skills.

so I was wonder how do they do it

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about how a specific game solved a specific problem are [off-topic](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Especially in a case like this, where "it runs faster and lighter" doesn't tell us anything about what the "GPU mode" in that particular game even *does*. But you could make this question on-topic if you reframed it as asking about how to solve a **specific** problem in a game *you* are developing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's hard to answer without knowledge of the code of that particular game, but there are all kinds of ways to have code executed on the GPU instead of the CPU.

CPUs are optimized to handle random new instructions with every operation while GPUs are VERY optimized for doing the same "simple" calculations repeatedly on a huge scale.

I recently made a unity project for visualizing data, like a chart. For each data point, a ball was positioned and given a color according to the data value. I calculated the positions and colors in the game code, which uses the CPU.

When I ran the code on data with thousands of data points, it ran very slowly. Each point had to be located by the CPU and updated every frame, THEN handed to the GPU to be rendered one-at-a-time, and there was a lot of processing overhead for features I didn't need.

To get more performance, I wrote a shader- this is code that runs only on the GPU. I was able to send my data directly to the GPU, and the GPU would draw each ball and add colors itself. It was perfect for my code, and it increased performance massively. My CPU-based code ran at 10fps on a large data set, while my new GPU-based one runs over 600fps with the same data.